# Can TypeScript infer a function return type based on an argument in this scenario?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a function that fetches data from an API. I know what the data will be based on the API path, so I tried an approach with 'ApiSignature' types.

I simplified the code I have at the moment:

```js
interface Order {
    id: string
}

type ApiSignature<P, D> = {
  path: P,
  data: D
};

type OrdersApiSignature = ApiSignature<'/orders', Order[]>
type OrderApiSignature = ApiSignature<'/order', Order>

type AnyApiSignature = OrdersApiSignature | OrderApiSignature

function useApi<T extends AnyApiSignature>(path: T['path']) {
    return null as any as T['data']
}

const data = useApi('/orders') // Order | Order[]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJQCbWQbwLABQyxywGAXMgM5hSgDmhAvoYWAJ4AOKAgp8AGVg9EHDABXKBAA8ABQA0yACIA+ZAF5chYpzEALSgu3IMYuJSXMA3KwIduaTNCp9Bw0RKkbkroSLGSMgDkAPQA9k5QVEGK6FhQANoAuipsXChx0L7uAV6a2f6eweGRMY7xqQRpDjwg7AUegd6ZUQ25KAA+5Vn8fo1StjDiIAhgwGEgyOJUEK7SACrIEAAekCAYVD51bUUqABS6YAbI8wlBh3pBSQCUWkQkUp6TIOIANq-IcJtwdZ+bp0FTGA4FdmLYEBMaCYzN5prN+HtQhF4tFbiEQt0oMgui1kkA)

Is it possible for TypeScript to infer that in this case the data will be `Order[]` and not `Order`, based on the function argument?

Comment: There's no good inference site for `T` here... the compiler can't perform arbitrarily complicated type inference, unfortunately.  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/N540Zw) where your generic type is just `P` corresponding to the `path` property and then use `Extract` to figure out which member of `AnyApiSignature` you want.  But if your path is a string then you can just do this more conventionally with a key lookup like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQ547w).  Would you like to see either of these fleshed out into an answer?

Comment: Those are both great solutions. I don't need an extended answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Building on @jcalz's comment,

> But if your path is a string then you can just do this more conventionally with a key lookup like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJQCbWQbwLABQyywGAXMgM5hSgDmhAvoYaJLIigApxgAWAEV5wAsnAAOuQsQDkAegD2maDIrosUADTTk8pRsqq0yqAG0AukxYEYAVxAIwwBSGS3KEAILjgAHgDSyBAAHpAgGJTIANYQAJ4KMMg8-EJgohIAfAAU4rx8FP4AlFJEyFAQYLZQriC2ADZ1yHCRcCCxTZHJgsJi4qb+lgTMBIQILtTIGMLIALxuHt7AWXomhsVycsYaFkA).

```
type ApiSignatureMap = {
  "/orders": Order[];
  "/order": Order;
};

type AnyApiSignature = {
  [K in keyof ApiSignatureMap]: ApiSignature<K, ApiSignatureMap[K]>;
}[keyof ApiSignatureMap];

function useApi<P extends AnyApiSignature["path"]>(path: P): ApiSignatureMap[P] { ... }
```

We'll use a "map" to map paths to the type of data (`ApiSignatureMap`).

And to get all the possible API signatures, we use a mapped type:

```
{
  [K in keyof ApiSignatureMap]: ApiSignature<K, ApiSignatureMap[K]>;
}
```

This will give us an object whose values are all the API signatures we seek.
To get a union of them we can use `keyof ApiSignatureMap`:

```
{
  [K in keyof ApiSignatureMap]: ApiSignature<K, ApiSignatureMap[K]>;
}[keyof ApiSignatureMap]
```

And finally in the function declaration, we have a generic `P` that can be any valid path in `AnyApiSignature`, then get the return type using the API signature map above.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJQCbWQbwLABQyxywGAXMgM5hSgDmhAvoYWAJ4AOKAgp8AGVg9EHDABXKBAA8ABQA0yACIA+ZAF5chYpzEALSgu3IMYuJSXMA3KwIduaTNCp9Bw0RKkbkroSLGSMgDkAPQA9k5QVEGK6FhQANoAuipsXChx0L7uAV6a2f6eweGRMY7xqQRpDgUegQCycJze+ETIAEQl8VTtlJmJSTZtnRHxveXQQ0xD1bwg7LW5KJqtxAkA0qQgyADWEOxhMD78fnVSjZxJlItF0uuKNw1NGylTCXsHR4-nTYO2WAgADZwLwwcQgBBgYBhbbiKgQVxyZAQAAekBAGCoPnm3wgCXaujAenaKQAFISDMhZABKa4nHJFC4JWR-KoEBAwmgmMzeOEI-ik0KjZxBalDEIhEjIAB6AH4gA)

Comment: This is also an option https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJQCbWQbwLABQyxywGAXMgM5hSgDmhAvoYWAJ4AOKAgp8AGVg9EHDABXKBAA8ABQA0yACIA+ZAF5chYpzEALSgu3IMYuJSXMA3KwIduaTNCp9Bw0RKkbkroSLGSMgDkAPQA9k5QVEGK6FhQANoAuipsXChx0L7uAV6a2f6eweGRMY7xqQRpDjwg7AUegd6ZUQ25KAA+5Vn8fo1StjDiIAhgwGEgyOJUEK5yyBAAHpAgGFQ+dW1FCUG6YHpBKQAUewbIsgCUWkQkUp6TIOIANk-IcOtwdW-rAKLLUIgwNJavVejkioocMhToZkEwVDtTGA4IdmLYEBMaCYzN5prN+EdQhF4tEriEQt1EklCOSSMQAHoAfkIGJAWOAkAAtriZq5CSV4kEyRSWjSKXSmUA

Comment: Thanks didn't know you could do that